# Monitor EC2 Instance with Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I tried this code to get EC2 Instance description:

```
public void testEC2ServiceInRegion() throws Exception
    {
        BasicAWSCredentials bawsc = new BasicAWSCredentials(
            "AKIAIUYDKF4K255DALPA", "Onv+nq3134kiLlKIb2H1JtIB7Y4QMEesh01Jl7tL");

        describeInstance(new AmazonEC2Client(bawsc), "i-02f5bd34");

    }

    private Instance describeInstance(AmazonEC2Client ec2, String ec2InstanceId)
    {
        Instance ec2Instance = null;
        {
            DescribeInstancesRequest request = new DescribeInstancesRequest();
            request.setInstanceIds(Collections.singletonList(ec2InstanceId));
            DescribeInstancesResult response = ec2.describeInstances(request);

            List<Reservation> reservations = response.getReservations();
            for (Reservation reservation : reservations)
            {
                for (Instance i : reservation.getInstances())
                {
                    if (ec2Instance != null)
                    {
                        throw new IllegalStateException();
                    }
                    ec2Instance = i;
                }
            }

            if (ec2Instance == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("EC2 instance not found: " + ec2InstanceId);
            }
        }
        return ec2Instance;
    }
```

But I get error

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The instance ID 'i-02f5bd34' does not exist (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound; Request ID: 4079522f-7cae-4a58-877a-051abb5035a2)
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Is there any example that I can use for getting Instance status?

Comment: You probably want to keep aws credentials out of stuff you post onlne.

Comment: Don't worry, they are not real.

Comment: Have you tried calling describe instances without an id? Then dump their ids in your inner loop and see whether any of them actually match the id you're looking for

Comment: Can you show me some example with Java? I'm new to AWS

Comment: just don't set the instance id on the request.  That will return all instances for all reservations. In your inner loop, you can dump them out or compare them to your instance id. AWS is complaining it doesn't know of such an instance id, this is a way to check by asking the API to give you everything.

Comment: Can you show me some example code please?

Comment: I can try to answer if you didn't understand something in the explanation but  there is no code here to write. Remove this `            request.setInstanceIds(Collections.singletonList(ec2InstanceId));
` and look at the instances in your inner loop.